# Is there actually a way to make video calls through XMPP/Jingle WITHOUT Google Talk?

Tags: linux, voip, xmpp

Good day people,

I'm writing because I've spent the whole day trying to make video calls through XMPP but I haven't really found out if it's actually possible. There are many clients which implemented Jingle (Empathy, Kopete and the one I like the most, Gajim) but I found no way to actually video call someone. Is it fault of the XMPP server? Is there a XMPP server that supports it? I've tried many at xmpp.net but if there is one, I must have missed it.

I don't trust Google and I don't want a Google account, is there a way for me to video call people on XMPP on Linux? SIP has been unstable in my experience and isn't really an alternative. Even non-XMPP videoconferencing software should be fine, as long as it's FOSS and runs on Linux.

(And yes, before you ask, my webcam does work correctly).

Comment: Have you found any solution ?

Comment: SIP is an excellent alternative to any audio/video/sms service offered by large tech companies. You most likely didn't have your network optimized for it...

Comment: What are the actual symptoms of your attempts to video call someone? For remote calls, if at least one peer is behind a symmetric NAT, a direct P2P connection may not be possible but a TURN server as relay required. Some but not all XMPP/Jingle implementations include it, otherwise a dedicated one like Coturn or Eturnal may work.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely problem is that your contacts don't have clients that support Jingle.

Answer (score 0):

Jingle doesn't require special server features.  XMPP clients supporting the Jingle protocol establish media channels directly between one another.

For video conferences with more than two participants you may want to take a look at the Jitsi video bridge.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use any clients supporting Jingle, such as [pidgin](http://www.pidgin.im) or [jitsi](http://jitsi.org).

A non-XMPP alternative would be [webRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/). It's browser based so you don't have to really worry about which OS you are on. [Firefox Hello](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-hello-video-and-voice-conversations-online) provides an easy way to call with webRTC without an account.